# What can cause my PC to BSOD (blue screen of death/ stop error)

Tags: windows-8, crash, bsod

Since a week or two I've been having many BSODS. It's not only one error, there are many. some of I could remember are:

-memory_management
-page_fault_in_nonpaged_area
-pfn_list_corrupt
-kernel_mode_heap_corrupt
-driver_IRQL_not_less_or_equal

I usually get them when I do something processor efficient like playing games.

Comment: There are many things which can cause that, so we can not answer this without more information. Did you change your PC configurartion a week or two ago? Did you install new software (e.g. new drivers). Did you make a memory dump and did you try to analyse that ? (You can find the setting ffor that in Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings (on the left panel) -> Settings in Startup and Recovery section.).

Comment: The above comments apply. Also, do the BSODs occur in safe mode? If so then it's probably a hardware issue. The RAM and mainboard would be the main culprits.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a memory issue.

I would run MEMTEST for a while.

Try to change the RAM (if you have spare). Or, use just 1 block and if the problem persists, then swap it for another (Assuming you have more than 1 RAM chip installed).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause is that your system is probably overheating.  Try cleaning it of any dust and make sure all fans are working.  Make sure it's in a well ventilated area and not stuffed in a desk cabinet or other air-movement-unfriendly spot.

The next most likely cause is a power supply issue.  Try replacing your power supply.

Of course, would not hurt to test the RAM as well.  If you have multiple RAM sticks, you can remove one and run your system for awhile, when the errors disappear, you know you've found the bad RAM stick (or sticks).